# get_template_part vs the_content?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have looked at several themes, and I see that  "the loop" often works something like this:

```
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    get_template_part('content');
}
```

The code that I developed for my theme looks like the following:

```
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_content();
}
```

My code works as well, and it was something I came up with before I looked at the code for the other themes. I understand that there must be a reason why `get_template_part('content')` is used, rather than `the_content()`. I think the reason has something to do with the ability to customize things in a child theme, but I have scrutinized the documentation and the WordPress code, and I can't really figure out what the difference is exactly.

So what is the advantages of using `get_template_part('content')` over`the_content()`?

Comment: get_template_part('content'); Makes it easy for a theme to reuse sections of code in a easy to overload way for child themes.

Includes the named template part for a theme or if a name is specified then a specialised part will be included. If the theme contains no {slug}.php file then no template will be included.

The template is included using require, not require_once, so you may include the same template part multiple times.
For the $name parameter, if the file is called "{slug}-special.php" then specify "special".

Comment: Ok. Why does it make it easier? Why isn't it possible to to overload if the_content is used? I guess what I'm asking is... If get_template_part('content') is the preferred what of doing it, how come the_content() doesn't call it implicitly? Why does the_content() even exist and why would someone want to use it? Or let me rephrase. It seems like the_content() has one purpose, and get_template_part('content') has another, but I can't figure out these two different purposes.

Comment: Read this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_template_part('content') & the_content() both are very different thing for use.

- the_content() -> this will directly take only content of the editor area of your page from admin to front.
- get_template_part('content') -> this will call to a file named content.php in your theme folder & take out put from that file, this file may can include html tags too after & before content of editor area.

in general case for all theme content.php has basic output code of editor, but when you are using any custom template then you may can use the_content() for easiness.